# How can I ping my home computer from outside?

Tags: networking

I'm trying to wrap my head around networking and the internet. This is a very big subject, and it is not my goal to understand all of it. However, I want to know how to use it for... stuff... which right now means I want to find a specific computer. I'm going for my home computer. I know the IP adress is alpha and omega when it comes to finding something online, so I have looked it up, by typing "my ip" into google. So far, so good.

However, I did the same on my phone, which is connected to the same wireless router, and lo and behold, it has the same IP address, according to google. So, if I am on a different computer, on a different network, and I try to ping that IP address, my best bet is that I'll reach that wireless router and that's that (I've checked in the router settings that that is indeed my router's IP address as well). How can I send a ping (as in, using the sommand `ping`, either on linux or windows) from somewhere else that goes out on the internet, and specifically finds *my computer*, instead of just the router controlling my home network?

Comment: The IP address you are seeing is the one your ISP gave you. Presumably whatever router you are using is doing some kind of network address translation, so the IPs internally are different then ones outside. In other words your router is doing stuff to keep your internal IP seperate from the external one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is completely off-topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your home router has a single IP address. The router's job is to use a network address translation (NAT) to figure out which computer or device on your home network sent which requests so that all the devices on your router can use the *same* external IP address.

The router also has port forwarding settings that you can look up so you can, for example, set up a game server or web server that directs all outside network traffic trying to use that port to that one specific computer. You can also DMZ a specific computer but that leaves that device open to attacks.

Answer (score 2):

To keep it simple: the devices in your home network do have an IP address, but it is a private IP address. In order to be able to reach your phone from the internet, it should have a public IP.
Unless you try to mess with the router, you can't reach any device from outside your network.

Answer (score 1):

Your PC lives underneath the router on a smaller network called your `LAN`. The internet cannot see it, it can only see your `router`, which in this case is serving as a `gateway`.

Pinging is difficult behind a router depending on whether your router uses PAT or NAT. In order to forward traffic to a specific `port` you can change a setting in your router to forward incoming traffic on that port to the local machine.